# rails app resubmitting on refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Sorry, this is a dumb question.

I am updating a model after form submission. Then rendering a page with the updated data. If I refresh the data is resubmitted. How can I void this. I tried making a method to update the model and redirect to another method to display the updated data, but couldn't get it to perform.

Here is my form and controller method:

```
<%= form_for :poll_answer, :url => "/results", :html => {:method => :put} do |f| %>
<ul>
  <% @poll_answers.each do |answer| %>
  <!-- <li><%#= answer.votes %></li> -->
    <li><%= f.radio_button :answer, answer.id %>
    <%= f.label answer.answer %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "poll_id", @poll.id %>
  <%= f.submit value: "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>


def results
    answer_id = params["poll_answer"].values[0]
    Answer.increment_vote_count answer_id
    poll_id = params["poll_id"]
    @answers = Answer.all.order("vote_count DESC")
    @total = 0
    @answers.each do |answer|
      vote_count = answer["vote_count"] ? answer["vote_count"] : 0
      @total = @total + vote_count
    end
    @question = Poll.find(params["poll_id"])

    render :results
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of directly rendering the page with `render`, you can use:

`redirect_to results_path`

This will render the page using a `GET` request, thus refreshing the page won't populate the form again

Comment: Yeah, I tried that but I get an error that there is not GET route for results.

Comment: Make sure your route is configured to accept PUT and GET requests: `match '/results/', to: 'controller#results', via: [:get, :put]`
Or redirect to another route accepting GET requests

Answer (score 0):

Rendering the form again after submission is bad practice, unless you DO WANT to resubmit it.

Build a view which you will call via 'get' method to display your data, or 'get' your form with `redirect_to`.